# Switch windowHandles and press Enter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I want to switch between all my tabs and press the ENTER key.

`web.SwitchTo().Window(web.WindowHandles[windowCounter]);
javascript.ExecuteScript("$('button').click();");`

in a for loop.
If I just loop with the SwitchTo and without the Javascript execution, it takes 7ms to swap between all tabs.

When I use the js it seems like it's waiting to finish loading the document. How can i just rapidly switch the tabs and press enter to all of them without waiting for load?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set capability `pageLoadStrategy` to `none`. However, it seems ChromeDriver doesn't support `DesiredCapability`. You may need a workaround. My example below uses `RemoteWebDriver` to set `DesiredCapability`. It will open a blank Chrome and close it for the first time.

```
string binLocation = @"./";
ChromeOptions chromeOpt = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOpt.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(binLocation);
service.Port = 9515;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOpt);
driver.Close();

var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options.Add("browserName", "chrome");
options.Add("pageLoadStrategy", "none");
var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(options);
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9515"), capabilities);

// do your works here //
////////////////////////

web.SwitchTo().Window(web.WindowHandles[windowCounter]);
// Make sure the button is clickable. You may use WebDriverWait.
javascript.ExecuteScript("$('button').click();");
```

Comment: are you sure it'll be fast? It just click this button in 4 tabs and the rangetime per tab is <200ms

Comment: @TNation it won't wait for page load so rangetime should be less than 1 ms.

Comment: I already got a driver open. The driver waits for pageloading. Can I just disable the waiting in runtime?

Comment: @TNation No, you can't.